# Continuous functions on a Suslin line

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

This question is motivated by Brian Scott's answer in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955717/a-question-on-zero-dimensional-spaces). It looks to me that continuous functions on Suslin lines may have remarkable properties (from my perspective).

*Convention*. I am interested in *compact Suslin lines*, that is, Suslin lines with adjoined points $\pm \infty$ making them compact in the order topology.

Here's my question:

> Suppose that $K$ is a compact Suslin line. Is it true that there is no **uncountable** family $F\subset C(K)$ of **norm-one** functions such that
>
> a) $\|f-g\| > 1+ \varepsilon$ for all $f,g\in F, f\neq g$ and some fixed $\varepsilon > 0$?
>
> b) $\|f-g\| > 1$ for all $f,g\in F, f\neq g$?

A *specific* (consistent) example of a compact Suslin line (or any non-metrisable, compact Hausdorff space $K$) which satisfies the above property would be very interesting.

I played with this problem myself trying to find a certain colouring of two-elements subsets which after using Dushnik-Miller would give me an uncountable discrete subset of $K$ (impossible for Suslin lines) but with no success so far.

I can show that in general, if $K$ contains a closed, non-metrisable, totally disconnected subspace or a closed subspace which is not ccc then b) cannot hold, *i.e.* there is such a family.

This is also related to a question by Todorcevic (see Question 11 [here](http://www.auburn.edu/%7Egruengf/preprints/basis1119.pdf)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\langle (x_i, J_i) : i < \omega_1 \rangle$ satisfy: $J_i$ is an interval containing $x_i$ and whenever $j < i$, $x_j \notin J_i$. Let $f_i: K \rightarrow [-1, 1]$ be any continuous function such that $f_i(x_i) = 1$ and $f_i(x) = -1$ if $x \notin J_i$. Then for all $i \neq j$, $||f_i|| = 1$ and $||f_i - f_j|| = 2$. This also works for any non separable $T_4$ space.